# Compiling PHP --with-php-config on OS X

Tags: php, makefile, mamp, configure, mamp-pro

My ultimate goal is to re-compile PHP 5.6.10 bundled with MAMP PRO with extra features (using `--with-imap-ssl` so I can connect to an IMAP mailbox with SSL).

I'm stuck at the first stage: to `configure` and `make` according to the default MAMP configuration. MAMP includes its own configuration in a config script.
In order to do so I've downloaded PHP 5.6.10 from php.net and extracted it to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/includes/php/`
After entering the following command:

```
$ ./configure --with-config-php=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php-config
```

I get

```
WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-php-config
```

How do I run `./configure` using the proper config script?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```
./configure --with-config-php=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php-config
```

You should use the following:

```
./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php-config
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still is telling me `configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-php-config`